# Setting a range to another range's visible cells only

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA, I'm trying to set the values of a new range to those or an existing range.  However the existing range has some hidden columns.  Assigning the range by selecting visible cells only results in the new range's values containing the first value from the source range just repeated.

VBA extract:

```
Range("E1:F1").Value = Range("A1:C1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Example Data with results:

[image: Example Data with results]

Comment: `Range("A1:C1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` has two areas, `A1` and `C1`. Unfortunately you cannot read the `.Value` of a multi-area range into an array, or assign it to another range, in one step. You have to loop.

Comment: Or you can copy/pastespecial

Comment: Ah OK - many thanks!